# Scoping issue when attempting to call CoffeeScript method inside Fancybox callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, coffeescript, scoping

I have the following CoffeeScript module named Course. I have a small piece of code which I would like to re-use, I have created a method called `preSelectItemSize`.

I would like to call this method when `init` is called and also within the `afterShow` Fancybox callback. The following code *works*, but it don't believe it is correct to use the module name and I should be using the `@` reference to "this" instead.

What am I doing wrong? (Code snippet reduced for brevity)

```
$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery")
Course =

  init: ->

    $('.js-product-overlay').on 'click', (e) =>
      @viewProductClickHandler(e, MediaDetection)

    @preSelectItemSize()

  viewProductClickHandler: (e, mediaDetection) =>

    $('.js-product-overlay').fancybox({
      href: wishlist_overlay_href
      maxWidth: '775px'
      minHeight: '495px'
      autoCenter: '!isTouch'
      height: 'auto'
      scrolling: true
      fitToView: false
      autoSize: false
      padding: 0
      tpl:
        closeBtn: '<a class="fancybox-item modal__close fancybox-close" href="javascript:;">Close</a>'
      afterShow: ->
        $('.js-fancybox-close').on 'click', (e) ->
          e.preventDefault()
          $.fancybox.close()

        Course.preSelectItemSize()
    })

  preSelectItemSize: ->
    itemId = $('.modal__product-info').attr('data-item-id')
    $('#size-' + itemId).click()

module.exports = Course
```

Comment: Do you just want `afterShow: =>` instead of `afterShow: ->`?

Comment: @muistooshort No, I initially used the "fat arrow" `=>1`, but this doesn't work. I just re-tried it and got `_this.preSelectItemSize is not a function`

Comment: Right, because you don't have a class, you just have an object literal, missed that.

Comment: This Fiddle has a working example https://jsfiddle.net/L5u31Lzr/1/

Comment: You can self-answer the question with that approach if it works for you.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works by changing the `viewProductClickHandler` to a thin arrow and changing the `afterShow` callback to a fat arrow:

```
Course =

  init: ->

    $('.js-product-overlay').on 'click', (e) =>
      @viewProductClickHandler(e, MediaDetection)

    @preSelectItemSize()

  viewProductClickHandler: (e, mediaDetection) ->

    $('.js-product-overlay').fancybox({
      href: wishlist_overlay_href
      maxWidth: '775px'
      minHeight: '495px'
      autoCenter: '!isTouch'
      height: 'auto'
      scrolling: true
      fitToView: false
      autoSize: false
      padding: 0
      tpl:
        closeBtn: '<a class="fancybox-item modal__close fancybox-close" href="javascript:;">Close</a>'
      afterShow: =>
        $('.js-fancybox-close').on 'click', (e) ->
          e.preventDefault()
          $.fancybox.close()

        @preSelectItemSize()
    })

  preSelectItemSize: ->
    alert "preSelectItemSize executed."
    itemId = $('.modal__product-info').attr('data-item-id')
    $("#size-#{itemId}").click()

Course.init()
```

See fiddle for example of working code: https://jsfiddle.net/L5u31Lzr/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think your real problem is that you're using a simple object literal rather than a class so `=>` doesn't quite behave the way you expect it to and you're left referring to `Course` by name.

If we look at a simplified example:

```
o =
  m: =>
```

we can see what's going on by looking at the JavaScript that gets produced:

```
var o;
o = {
  m: (function(_this) {
    return function() {};
  })(this)
};
```

Because we have just a simple data structure (i.e. a plain old object literal), there is no constructor to bind `m` to any instance and it behaves as though you said:

```
m = =>
o = m: m
```

so any function properties of `o` (or `Course` in your case) are just plain old properties that happen to be functions, they're not really methods.

You could drop all the fat-arrows and refer to `Course` by name or you could switch to a class so that there is an instance for CoffeeScript to bind things to:

```
class Course
  #...
module.exports = new Course
```

Comment: Using an object literal is a pattern used throughout the system, so i'd be breaking the pattern if I changed it to a class. Is there no other way I can call this method without refactoring to a class?